# Best method to get Country/Territory picklist values from Salesforce API

Tags: rest-api, metadata-api

Is there currently any way to get the values of the Country/Territory picklists via REST API call from Salesforce?
I can see there are other methods, but currently the only method via the REST API appears to be to do an SObject Describe then extract the values of this from the results for the whole object, which is potentially quite a large resultset.
Would love to know a better way to call this if anyone has one.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the metadata API to retrieve all `Settings` and then in the result, filter out just the `Address` Settings

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Settings</name>
    </types>
    <version>58.0</version>
</Package>
```

if this is a one-off thing, you could use

- Your IDE to retrieve all Settings and then pull out the AddressSettings file
- A devops product (e.g Gearset) to fetch the Settings as such product will break out the Address Settings into a selectable element that you can copy-paste
- Fetch the Address Settings file from your version control system (assuming you are versioning this metadata)